# Printing values from different lists together

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner in Powershell and I am seeking help on completing a task.

I have two lists namely:

```sh
$name = "a,b,c"

$number = "1,2,3"
```

I want to print a value from list1 and list2 together in the below format:

```text
{ name = "a", number = "1" }, { name = "b", number = "2" }, { name = "c", number = "3" }
```

I have tried the below code but I am not achieving the desired result:

```sh
Clear-Host
$list1 = "a,b,c"
$list2 = "1,2,3"

foreach ($i in $list1)
{
  $temp1 = $list1 -split ","

  foreach ($j in $list2)
  {
    $temp2 = $list2 -split ","
  }

  $output = "{ value1 = ""$i"", value2 = ""$j"" }"
  echo $output
}
```

I get the below output after executing the code:

```text
{ name = "a,b,c", number = "1,2,3" }
```

Comment: That format looks suspiciously like a PowerShell hash table, or an attempt at JSON. Are you sure you need that as a string? It matters because if the intent is to create objects (and/or JSON) you need a different approach.

Comment: `$list1.Split(','), $list2.Split(',') | Join-Array -Columns name, number | ConvertTo-Json` using the function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73640310/different-length-arrays-to-one-csv/73640422#73640422)

Comment: You need to find a way to iterate over both arrays _at once_, which isn't directly supported by PowerShell (unfortunately). As a workaround you may use a plain old `for` counting loop or a `foreach` with an additional counter variable.

Comment: Have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31253263/7571258). Chances are that you may want to use a single _hashtable_ instead of two arrays, as explained in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
$name = "a,b,c"
$number = "1,2,3"

$name = $name.Split(",")
$number = $number.Split(",")
$length = $name.Length

$result = [string]::Empty
for($i =0; $i -lt $length;$i++)
{
    $result+= "{ name=""$($name[$i])"", number=$($number[$i]) }, "
}

Write-Host $result.Substring(0,$result.Length-2)
```

**Output**

```
{ name="a", number=1 }, { name="b", number=2 }, { name="c", number=3 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something to turn the *strings* that you currently have into actual lists (or arrays). You can use the `String.Split()` method for this:

```
$list1 = 'a,b,c'.Split(',')
```

Then to iterate over each item in both lists simultaneously, you can use a traditional `for` loop - the loop keeps track of the index variable and you can then access the corresponding items in both lists:

```
$list1 = "a,b,c".Split(',')
$list2 = "1,2,3".Split(',')

$newList = for ($i = 0; $i -lt [Math]::Max($list1.Length, $list2.Length); $i++){
  "{ value1=""$($list1[$i])"", value2=""$($list2[$i])"" }"
}
```

Replace `[Math]::Max` with `[Math]::Min` if you only want pairs that have a value in both lists.

---

Another option is to "stitch together" the two lists into a new one using [the LINQ `Zip()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0):

```
$list1 = 'a,b,c'.Split(',')
$list2 = '1,2,3'.Split(',')

$newList = [Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($list1, $list2, [Func[string,string,string]]{
  param($a,$b) 

  return "{ value1=""$a"", value2=""$b"" }"
})
```

This method will only continue until it exhausts the shortest of the two lists.